# Segundo plano cordova / phonegap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, apache-cordova

sou iniciante na área de criação de apps com cordova , já procurei por toda a internet mas não achei nenhum tutorial que explicasse exatamente como usar o plugin para segundo plano, em todas as perguntas que vi aqui são as mesmas respostas que eu não consigo entender espero que vocês possam me ajudar vamos lá.

estou criando um aplicativo em cordova que controla a dieta do usuário com horários pré definidos pelo proprio aplicativo informando a hora de comer e outras coisas , o aplicativo está funcionando 100% mas só funciona os alarmes quando está aberto, preciso que ele funcione também após o usuário apertar o botão back no android achei esse plugin no gitHub

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode#usage

tentei rodar a linha de comando

cordova plugin add de.appplant.cordova.plugin.background-mode --searchpath path

mas essa linha adiciona toda a pasta do gitHub Master dentro da pasta plugin e eu não sei o que fazer com esses arquivos,  alguém poderia me ajudar e dizer exatamente onde colocar os arquivos e onde chamar cada um dos arquivos?

fico grato a ajuda de todos , obrigado desde já.

Answer (score 3):

Pessoalmente nunca experimentei criar uma aplicação capaz de funcionar em segundo plano, no entanto sei que existe um plugin capaz de fazer isso:

https://github.com/Red-Folder/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/BackgroundService

Aí podes encontrar [tutoriais](https://github.com/Red-Folder/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/BackgroundService/2.0.0#further-information) e como o [instalar](https://github.com/Red-Folder/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/BackgroundService/2.0.0#adding-the-plugin-to-your-project).